# How to connect to friendly URL socket?

Tags: javascript, php, sockets

I accustomed to use HTML5 websockets on JavaScript, where you can connect with an instruction like this one:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/socket/server/socketEndpoint");
```

I need to do a similar connection but with PHP. According to the documentation, I can use "socket_connect", but I need an IP address and a PORT. I have the port, but is inside the URL and I don't know how to use it in socket_connect.

Any ways to connect to that URL with PHP? I need another instruction? Thanks to all.

Comment: Why do you need a low-level [TCP socket](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) connection (w/ implementing HTTP, Upgrade: and whatnot), rather than using a WebSocket client in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Pawl](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl)** for that (an asynchronous WebSocket client in PHP).

You can install it via composer: `composer require ratchet/pawl`

**Using your connection details, the result would be:**

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

\Ratchet\Client\connect('ws://localhost:8000/socket/server/socketEndpoint')->then(function($conn) {
    $conn->on('message', function($msg) use ($conn) {
        echo "Received: {$msg}\n";
        $conn->close();
    });
    $conn->send('Hello World!');
}, function ($e) {
    echo "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
});
```